# Join 3 column from 3 tables into different row record

Tags: mysql

I Have 3 tables,

1. Table `senitems`
2. Table `inbox`
3. Table `outbox`

how join into 1 tables, look at to this link for image illustration:

[image]

please help

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `JOIN` for this, what you need is [`UNION ALL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html):

```
SELECT 
  SendingDateTime AS DateTime,
  DestinationNumber AS PhoneNumber,
  SMS,
  'sentitems' AS Folder
FROM sentitems
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  ReceivingDateTime, SenderNumber, SMS,
  'inbox'
FROM inbox
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  InserDateTime, DestinationNumber, SMS,
  'outbox'
FROM outbox;
```

**Note that:** The columns' names for the final result set will be inferred from the first query.

---

If you want to order the result set, put that query in a subquery and `ORDER BY` in the outer one, something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      SendingDateTime AS DateTime,
      DestinationNumber AS PhoneNumber,
      SMS,
      'sentitems' AS Folder
    FROM sentitems
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
      ReceivingDateTime, SenderNumber, SMS,
      'inbox'
    FROM inbox
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
      InserDateTime, DestinationNumber, SMS,
      'outbox'
    FROM outbox
) AS sub
ORDER BY DateTime
```